# Inserting specific JSON object properties from file in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a "data.txt" file that contains multiple articles as JSON data with attributes like:

```
{"title":"...","abstract":"...","authors":[{"surname":"Dodson","given_names":"S I"},{"surname":"Hanazato","given_names":"T"}],"biblio":{"journal":{"title":"Environmental Health Perspectives","issn":""},"year":"1995","volume":"103","issue":"Suppl 4","fpage":"7","lpage":"11"},"pmid":"7556027"}
```

I want to add all the articles into a `docs` table (`id int` generated by default as identity primary key, title text, abstract text).

I tried the following SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp (c text);
copy tmp from 'C:\data.txt'

INSERT INTO docs(title, abstract)
    SELECT q.title, q.abstract 
    FROM tmp, json_populate_record(null::docs, c::json) AS q;
```

But I'm getting this error:

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
> DETAIL:  Token "recorder" is invalid.
> CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ..., each measuring changes in a different "recorder...
> SQL state: 22P02

I want the final table to have:

- An auto-increment ID (already configured that to the table column settings)
- the title
- abstracts of each article

Any ideas on what's the problem here? Thank you a lot in advance for
your time!

Comment: Your double quote is not escaped properly.

Comment: @jjanes Fixed that with: copy tmp from 'C:\Users\...\Desktop\data.txt'; . I'm still getting the same message as an error.

Comment: No, the double quote inside your txt file is not escaped properly.  Whatever created that file did not do it correctly, or at least not compatibly with COPY and JSON.